# Analytic Continuation of the $S$-Matrix and Analytic Continuation of Spinors

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, group-theory, unitarity, analyticity

Broadly speaking, what is actually being done when one analytically continues the external particles' momenta in scattering amplitudes in QFT?

Some associated more detailed questions:

When thinking of the quantum fields that go into the Green's functions that give the $S$-matrix by LSZ, these fields transform in the irreps of the homogeneous Lorentz group; what's the correct generalization of $O(1,3,\mathbb{R})$ when we analytically continue?  "Trivially" one could use the complexification $O(1,3,\mathbb{C})$, trivially since one often complexifies anyway in order to determine the irreps anyway.  In this case, what are the explicit polarization vectors $u_{ab}(\vec{p},\sigma)$?  Of particular interest to me are the Weyl left- and right-handed spinors: how does $$u_a(\vec{p},s=1/2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2(E_{\vec{p}}+m)}}\left(\begin{array}{c} E_{\vec p}-p^3+m \\ -p^1-i\,p^2 \end{array}\right),$$ etc. change when $\vec{p}\in\mathbb{C}^3$?  (Basically, what is the correct way to treat $p^0=E_{\vec p} = \sqrt{\vec p^2+m^2}$ when $\vec{p}\in\mathbb{C}^3$?) Similar question for the 2D helicity polarization vectors.  A pointer to a readable (for a physicist) reference would be invaluable!

On the other hand, wouldn't it be more natural to use $U(1,3,\mathbb{R})$ (or $U(1,3,\mathbb{C})$) since everything in quantum mechanics is unitary as opposed to orthogonal?  Is there a physical reason that the metric in the analytic continuation is bilinear $$p^2 = (p^0)^2 - \sum_i (p^i)^2$$ instead of sesquilinear $$p^2 = |p^0|^2 - \sum_i|p_i|^2;$$ it again seems more natural to me to keep $m^2\in\mathbb{R}$. (Since the analytic continuation of the S matrix is unique due to the edge-of-the-wedge theorem, is there in fact no difference?)  Again, any easy to read reference that goes through the construction and examples of the finite dimensional irreps of $SU(1,3,\mathbb{R})$?

Along this line of thought: what's going on with the Poincaré group when we analytically continue the momenta in the S matrix?  Presumably the spatial translations are complex, too, so is the correct generalization $T_4(\mathbb{C})\rtimes O(1,3,\mathbb{C})$?  Are there any readable resources on the Wigner program for the generalization of the Poincaré group that's associated with analytic continuation of the S matrix?  (Barut seems to have some partial answers in "Complex Lorentz Group with a Real Metric: Group Structure" and in "Symposium on Lorentz Group" [which I can't find a copy of anywhere]; he finds that particles are classified by $m^2$ but doesn't complete the classification or make a connection to our usual notions of spin or helicity from $O(1,3,\mathbb{R})$.)

I'll deeply appreciate any even partial answers to some of these questions.